# How to specify Dagger 2 Qualifier Annotation to Provider function Constructor parameter?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have my Dagger 2 Qualifier defined

```
@Qualifier
@MustBeDocumented
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class TrackerQualifier(val value: TrackerType)

enum class TrackerType {
    INTERNAL,
    EXTERNAL
}
```

And it works well, with

```
@Provides
@TrackerQualifier(TrackerType.INTERNAL)
@Singleton
UsageTracker providesInternalTracker(InternalTracker analyticsTracker) {
    return new UsageTracker(analyticsTracker);
}

@Provides
@TrackerQualifier(TrackerType.EXTERNAL)
@Singleton
UsageTracking providesExternalTracker(ExternalTracker eventTracker) {
    return eventTracker;
}
```

However, if I like to send it though to another injected module.

```
@Provides
fun provideCommonImage(
        imageEngine: ImageEngine,
        externalUsageTracking: UsageTracking) =
        CommonImage(imageEngine, externalUsageTracking)
```

It will compile fail, as it doesn't know is the `externalUsageTracking: UsageTracking` above is `INTERNAL` or `EXTERNAL`. How could I annotate it to the parameter?

Comment: post.a valid example , somewhere it is `UsageTracking` and somewhere it is `UsageTracker` and try a small code, you might be surprised

Comment: @Elye,you need to supply qualifier for function argument to allow Dagger propely resolve dependency. Something like that `@Provides
fun provideCommonImage(
        imageEngine: ImageEngine,
        @TrackerQualifier(TrackerType.EXTERNAL) externalUsageTracking: UsageTracking) =
        CommonImage(imageEngine, externalUsageTracking)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to explicit the qualifier.

```
@Provides
fun provideCommonImage(
        imageEngine: ImageEngine,
        @TrackerQualifier(TrackerType.EXTERNAL) tracker: UsageTracker) =
        CommonImage(imageEngine, tracker)
```